# Application won't minimise to the notification bar

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, notifyicon

I still can't get this to work, nothing appears in the notification bar. This is the full code to minimise, so far:

```
private void button6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized;
}

private void Form_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (WindowState == FormWindowState.Minimized)
    {
        this.Hide();
    }
}

private void notifyIcon_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Show();
    this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
}
```

Why isn't this working?

Comment: what you are trying to do ?

Comment: He is trying to hide the application, in the system tray

Comment: yes, i need the app to disapear on button press and only display in the system tray

Comment: i think minimizing a windows will definitely show the application in the bar just hide the application or hide the form and make context menu on notification icon and using that notification icon you can show the application.

Comment: the code above doesn't work, what is wrong with it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You never *display* anything in the notification area. Trace through your code and try to see what's happening. I've added some comments:

```
private void button6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // When button 6 is clicked, minimize the form.
    this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized;
}

private void Form_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Catch the case where the form is minimized, including but not limited to
    // clicks on button 6.
    if (WindowState == FormWindowState.Minimized)
    {
        // In that case, hide the form.
        this.Hide();
    }
}

private void notifyIcon_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // If the notification icon is clicked, reshow the form as a normal window.
    this.Show();
    this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
}
```

Notice the problem now? When the form is minimized, all you do is hide it. You never tell the `NotifyIcon` to display its icon! The default value of its [`Visible` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.notifyicon.visible.aspx) is `false`. You have to set it to `true` to make the icon show up, and `false` to get it to go away.

So modify your code as follows:

```
private void Form_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Catch the case where the form is minimized, including but not limited to
    // clicks on button 6.
    if (WindowState == FormWindowState.Minimized)
    {
        // In that case, hide the form.
        this.Hide();

        // And display the notification icon.
        notifyIcon.Visible = true;

        // TODO: You might also want to set other properties on the
        // notification icon, like Text and/or Icon.
    }
}

private void notifyIcon_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // If the notification icon is clicked, reshow the form as a normal window.
    this.Show();
    this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;

    // And hide the icon in the notification area.
    notifyIcon.Visible = false;
}
```

Comment: thanks but im still getting the error: The name notifyIcon does not exist in the current context

Comment: Well then what is your notification icon control called? I assumed it was `notifyIcon` since the name of your `Click` event handler method is `notifyIcon_Click`. It might be something like `notifyIcon1`. Check in the designer where you added it to the form and see what it's named. @connor

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
private NotifyIcon notifyIcon;
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    button6.Click += (sender, e) =>
        {
            this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized;
        };

    this.Resize += (sender, e) =>
        {
            if (WindowState == FormWindowState.Minimized)
            {
                this.Hide();
                notifyIcon.Visible = true;
                notifyIcon.ShowBalloonTip(1000);
            }
        };

    notifyIcon = new NotifyIcon()
        {
            Text = "I'm here!",
            BalloonTipText = "I'm here!",
            Icon = Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon(Application.ExecutablePath)
        };

    notifyIcon.Click += (sender, e) =>
        {
            this.Show();
            this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
            notifyIcon.Visible = false;
        };
}
```